# Access elements of loaded FXML in Parent Controller

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

I currently have the following situation:

I have created a FXML file backed up by a FXML Controller. The screen consists of a sidebar and a child holder. When I click on an element in the sidebar, I load an additional FXML file in the child holder, like this:

```
childHolder.getChildren().addAll(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SidebarItem1.fxml")));
```

This works fine. But I want to access some elements of the loaded FXML in the Controller of the Parent Controller. I just initialized the elements of the child FXML after I loaded it.

I already looked at this question: [JAVAFX - FXML - Access Loaded FXML Controls from Parent Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801365/javafx-fxml-access-loaded-fxml-controls-from-parent-controller), but when I do it like that, I still get an error:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SidebarItem1.fxml"));
loader.setController(this);
childHolder.getChildren().addAll(loader.load());

someChildTextField.setText("Some text");
```

I have given `someChildTextField` a `fx:id` and I have placed it on top of the initialize like this:

```
@FXML public TextField someChildTextField;
```

Still, I get a NullpointerException, so I assume it can still not find the control.

Does anyone know how to access elements of a loaded FXML in the Parent Controller?

Comment: It should work, though it's an unusual setup to have the same object acting as a controller for two different FXML files. Check you have the `fx:id` set correctly (post that portion of the FXML if necessary). Also check that it really is `someChildTextField` that is `null`.

Comment: Should I just create separate controllers then?

Comment: On the other hand, I still don't get it to work. I have set up the `fx:id` correctly, and it is really `someChildTextField` that is `null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't see any reason your approach doesn't work; I mocked something similar up and it worked just fine. This is an unusual approach, though, as you are using the same object as a controller for two separate FXML files.

I would recommend using one controller for each FXML. So you could do something like

```
public class SidebarItem1Controller {

    @FXML
    private TextField someTextField ;

    public void setText(String text) {
        someTextField.setText(text);
    }

}
```

and then from your parent controller just do

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SidebarItem1.fxml"));
childHolder.getChildren().add(loader.load());
SideBarItem1Controller childController = loader.getController();
childController.setText("Some Text");
```

Set the controller in your SideBarItem1.fxml file the usual way, with `fx:controller = com.example.SidebarItem1Controller"`

Comment: Thanks for your advice James_D, I also still don't know why it doesn't work. I will now use separate controllers, as I can see it is much better.